# PHP text output in clauses

Tags: php, if-statement

I am working on a PHP project. There, I often use following syntax to output text in a cluase:

```
if($boolean){

?>
output text
<?

}else{

?>
alternative
<?

}
```

On my computer, this works perfectly well. I use XAMPP foer Mac OS X. But when I send the files to my coworker, these outputs often do not work and the compiler complains about having reached an unexpected $end of file. This occurs especially often when there is a  tag in the output. We have to replace the means of output with echo.

What's the reason for this strange behavior of the compiler? Is the above-mention syntax of outputting text wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<?php` instead of `<?` he might not have short tags enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find this topic useful;

[Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)